# highcharts: how insert a fix label on a chart

Tags: highcharts, label

i would like to know if there is a method to add a fixed label on a chart, for example near to a line or on a column histogram

Thank you very much

Cinzia

Answer (score 0):

You can use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) which allows to add custom text.

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much; i'm using chart.renderer.text but i can't set the attribute x and y. i'm starting by the last value of a serie that i computed in this way

` var dataY = chart.yAxis[0].series[2].processedYData;
                            var dataX = chart.xAxis[0].series[2].processedXData;
                            var Y = dataY[dataY.length - 1];
                            var X = dataX[dataX.length - 1];`

but these are the represented values, not the attributes x and y that i need to place the text on the graph.
can you help me?

thank youuuuuuuuuu 
Cinzia

Comment: x, y value which you use is value not coordinates, but renderer use coordinates.

Comment: Hi sebastian, i know that they are not the coordinates...and i would like to know how can i compute them by x and y values.

Comment: You can use toPixels / toValue tranlate function. Both of them are documented here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Comment: Sorry but where do i have to use these two functions? i'm trying to use them on the chart.yAxis[0].series[2] and on the chart.xAxis[0] but they don't work. can you show me some explicit examples? of course i have the two data values of the xaxis and yaxis like i showed before. Thank you very very much

Comment: You can get coordinates of point and then use these to return in renderer or use values of point and translate by functiosn which I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

i want to show my solution. i have computed the points in this way

```
var lPoints = chart.series[1].points.length;
var plotx = chart.plotLeft + chart.series[1].points[lPoints - 1].plotX;
var ploty = chart.plotTop + chart.series[1].points[lPoints - 1].plotY;
```

then i used plotx and ploty to set the render of the text

var text = chart.renderer.text("LA TUA META", plotx, ploty) ecc......

Hi Cinzia